# How To Output CountryName Appropriately?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the `Username`, `LastName`, `JoinDate` and `CountryName` for all the users who joined **after** the 13th January 2017 in ascending order.

I'm struggling to understand what type of join I should use and how to connect the two tables together, If you have any ideas or more knowledge than I do, please let me know.

### An attempt of my code is below:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
"Username", 
"LastName", 
"JoinDate", 
"CountryId"
FROM BR_USER, BR_COUNTRY
WHERE "JoinDate" > '01-JAN-17'
LEFT JOIN BR_USER ON BR_USER."CountryId" = BR_COUNTRY."CountryId"
GROUP BY BR_USER."CountryId"
ORDER BY "JoinDate" ASC;
```

### How the two tables are created below:

---

[image: How the two tables are created below:]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.  The `WHERE` clause follows the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT u."Username", u."LastName", u."JoinDate", u."CountryId"
FROM BR_USER u JOIN
     BR_COUNTRY c
     ON u."CountryId" = c."CountryId"
WHERE u."JoinDate" > DATE '2017-01-01'
ORDER BY u."JoinDate" ASC;
```

When I write SQL statements, you will note that the clauses are aligned on the left and operators tend to be at the end of a row.  This format is consistent in the `SELECT`, `FROM` and `WHERE` clause.

Notes:

- Aggregation does not seem necessary.  I don't see why users would be duplicated in a table called `BR_USERS`.
- The `JOIN` seems utterly superfluous, given that you are not using any columns from `BR_COUNTRY`.
- I assume that all `CountryId`s are correct in `BR_USER`.  If not, use a `LEFT JOIN`.
- Learn to use the `DATE` keyword followed by YYYY-MM-DD.  This is a safer way to provide date constants.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read, particularly with escaped column and table names.
- Qualify all column references.

Comment: I'm getting the error message ```ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined``` Any ideas?

Comment: @UnboundPhantom . . . All columns are aliased in this query, so you should not be getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
 SELECT bru.username,
               bru.lastname,
               bru.joindate,
               bru.countryid
 from br_user bru join br_country brc
 on bru.countryid = brc.countryid
where bru.joindate > DATE '2017-01-01'
order by bru.joindate asc;
```

As always, try to make a english statement of the problem. 
For example: i need all the users even if they dont have countryid and who joined after 1st Jan 2017.

Also, please take care of boundary conditions whether or not to include 1st Jan 217.